# Look for coordinates - display an info window with a name on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, infowindow, google-maps-api-2

In Google Maps v2 [GClientGeocoder.getLocations()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GClientGeocoder) you can search for an address or for GLatLng.

Is there a way to combine these two, namely:

- search for a string containing both values, something like `Home @12.345,21.8970`
- have the **result (anchored at the coordinates) on map with a place name (`Home`) in the info window**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found. :)

Type into Google Maps search field:

```
12.345,21.8970 (Whatever)
```

or try the link http://maps.google.com/maps?q=12.345,21.8970+(Whatever)&iwloc=A